# Do UPS, USPS, and Fedex APis allow access to shipping address from a barcode?

Tags: api, fedex, ups, usps

Basically, I want to setup something where the qrcode/barcode that's on a package is scanned, sent to a server, and that the server pings the relevant API (UPS, USPS, Fedex), and is returned the shipping address.  Do these three company's offer something like that? I looked through their API docs and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

For USPS, there is no such capability.  If the shipping label is for domestic use, you can scan the barcode (called the IMpb -- Intelligent Mail Parcel Barcode) and the first portion of the barcode will contain the destination ZIP5 but that's all. The ZIP5 is prefaced by the numbers "420".  You can only "see" this prefix information by scanning the barcode -- it is not shown in the human-readable number below the barcode.  USPS does have internal API's which will return the complete delivery address (as well as other information about the shipment), but these are not publicly available.